# Create function posting multiple models

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a .NET Core 2.0 application and I have a single view with many instances of two different models, *Component* and *Value*. I want to create and post all instances of these models to the database, but I am having trouble posting them all. Currently only the first instance (row) of the two models are posted to the Db.

So my question: Is it possible to do such a thing? And if so is the case, how?

Below is a couple of samples from my code.

My ViewModel:

```
public class SheetData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Sheet Sheet { get; set; }
    public Component Components { get; set; }
    public Values Values { get; set; }
}
```

Razorview: (Only a small sample of the whole view)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Components.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Components.Name" class="form-control" value="UpperAnnular" readonly />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Values.OpenTime" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Values.OpenTime" class="form-control" />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Values.OpenGal" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Values.OpenGal" class="form-control" />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Values.CloseTime" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Values.CloseTime" class="form-control" />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Values.CloseGal" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Values.CloseGal" class="form-control" />
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Components.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Components.Name" class="form-control" value="LowerAnnular" readonly />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Values.OpenTime" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Values.OpenTime" class="form-control" />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Values.OpenGal" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Values.OpenGal" class="form-control" />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Values.CloseTime" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Values.CloseTime" class="form-control" />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>
                    <label asp-for="Values.CloseGal" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Values.CloseGal" class="form-control" />
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
// GET:
    public IActionResult Sheet ()
    {
        var model = new SheetData();
        model.Sheet = new Sheet();
        model.Components = new Component();
        model.Values = new Values();
        //model.Events = new Event();

        return View(model);
    }


    // POST: Sheet/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Sheet(SheetData viewModel)
    {
        Sheet sheet = viewModel.Sheet;
        Component component = viewModel.Components;
        Values values = viewModel.Values;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //values.ComponentID = component.ComponentID;

            _context.Add(sheet);
            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            _context.Add(values);
            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            component.SheetID = sheet.ID;
            component.ValuesID = values.ID;

            _context.Add(component);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `Values` property must be a collection (eg. a `List`).
Then on your Razor page you can point to each element by its index:

```
            <span>
                <label asp-for="Values[0].OpenTime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Values[0].OpenTime" class="form-control" />
            </span>
```

Comment: Getting index out of range, and I am unsure where to specify the length of the list. Do you have an idea of where to do that?

Comment: Instead of hard coding the indexes on your razor view you can use a `for` loop and setting the list size on your controller. For instance when instantiating your model (adding empty elements).

Comment: I went for this method and it worked wonderfully! In the controllers for the GET function i had to put my items inside a ViewBag before passing them to the View. Thanks Mr. polkduran

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just lazy, but I find it cleaner to use the database directly than to make more viewmodels.

I usually add the models to the "main" model like a `virtual`, then in the repository, I just include it: `return: db.Components.Include(C => C.Values)`

This allows me to use the other model just fine in the view, just that I'd have to add `.Values` whenever I want to add it.